# No UTF-32 big-endian in C#?

Tags: c#, text, encoding, endianness, utf-32

In C#, `Encoding.UTF32` is UTF-32 little-endian, `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` is UTF-16 big-endian, `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF-16 little-endian. But I can't find any for UTF-32 big-endian.

I'm developing a simple textviewer and don't think there are many documents encoded in UTF-32 big-endian but I want to prepare for that too, just in case.

**Doesn't C# support UTF32 big-endian?**

BTW Java supports it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf32encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx seems to indicate that the byte order is a parameter to the constructor -- is that something different than you had in mind?

Comment: Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-32be") is a simple way to get one.

Comment: Thanks for the informative replies both of you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does support big endian on UTF-32. Just create the encoding yourself using the [overloaded constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzs928d7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Encoding e = new UTF32Encoding(true /*bigEndian*/, true /*byteOrderMark*/);
```

The encodings predefined as `static` on `Encoding` aren't an exhaustive list. You can create much and much more other encodings.

Comment: I found a few resources that said it could be done but not explicitly how to do it - nice work!

Comment: Wow! you saved me! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.7.2
//12000 utf-32  Unicode (UTF-32)    ✓   ✓
//12001 utf-32BE    Unicode (UTF-32 Big endian)
const string strUniRepChr = "�"; //Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)
Encoding cpUTF32 = Encoding.GetEncoding(12000,
                   new EncoderReplacementFallback(strUniRepChr),
                   new DecoderReplacementFallback(strUniRepChr) );
```